# Узнать какой QCheckBox выбрал пользователь

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qcheckbox

Есть программа на *Python* с использованием *PyQt5*.
Имеются **`2`** `checkBox`, которые отвечают за выбор пола (названия: *PolMuzh*, *PolZhen*)

Я написал функцию, при которой, если один из чекбоксов нажат, второй чекбокс нажать нельзя.

Мне нужно узнать какой чекбокс выбрал пользователь и мне нужно, чтобы я мог использовать выбор.

```
self.PolMuzh.stateChanged.connect(self.selectCombo1)
self.PolZhen.stateChanged.connect(self.selectCombo2)

    def selectCombo1(self, toggle):
        if toggle == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            self.PolZhen.setEnabled(False)
        else:
            self.PolZhen.setEnabled(True)

    def selectCombo2(self, toggle):
        if toggle == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            self.PolMuzh.setEnabled(False)
        else:
            self.PolMuzh.setEnabled(True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.checkOne = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('one')
        self.checkTwo = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('two')
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.cb = ''
        
        self.vlayout  = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vlayout.addWidget(self.checkOne)
        self.vlayout.addWidget(self.checkTwo)
        self.vlayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(self.vlayout)
        
        self.checkOne.stateChanged.connect(self.selectBooks1)    
        self.checkTwo.stateChanged.connect(self.selectBooks2)  
        
        self.user_selected()                                    # +

    def selectBooks1(self, toggle):
        if toggle == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            self.cb = 'пользователь выбрал: one'
            self.checkTwo.setEnabled(False)                           
        else:
            self.cb = ''
            self.checkTwo.setEnabled(True)  
        self.user_selected()
            
    def selectBooks2(self, toggle):
        if toggle == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            self.cb = 'пользователь выбрал: two'
            self.checkOne.setEnabled(False)
        else:
            self.cb = ''
            self.checkOne.setEnabled(True)
        self.user_selected()
            
    def user_selected(self):
        if self.cb:
            self.label.setText(self.cb)
        else: 
            self.label.setText('пользователь пока ничего не выбрал.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @Noob пожалуйста